# Laravel Eloquent Relationship -- How to Combine two Relationships on id and date?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to pull spend and revenue by day for each of my websites.

I have a model for websites where I am triyng to build this as a relationship.

I already have relationships for each spend, and revenue that work

```
public function daily_spend() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Spend')->
        selectRaw('sum(spend) as spend, sum(clicks) as clicks, sum(leads) as leads, website_id, DATE( created_at ) as date' )->
        groupBy( DB::raw( 'website_id, DATE( created_at )' ) )->
        orderBy( DB::raw( 'DATE( created_at )' ) );
}
public function daily_revenue() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Spend')->
        selectRaw('sum(impressions) as impressions, sum(revenue) as revenue, sum(clicks) as clicks, sum(clicks) as unscored_tq_count, sum(case when tq > 0 then clicks else 0 end) as scored_tq_count, sum(case when tq >= 0 then tq * clicks else 0 end) as tq, website_id')->
        groupBy('website_id')->
        orderBy( DB::raw( 'DATE( created_at )' ) );
}
```

Then to get this data I call like so:

```
$start = '2019-02-01 00:00:00';
$stop = '2019-02-21 23:59:59';
Website::with( array( 
    'daily_spend' => function( $query ) use ( $start, $stop ) {
        $query->whereBetween( 'created_at', [ $start, $stop ] );
    },
    'daily_revenue' => function( $query ) use ( $start, $stop ) {
        $query->whereBetween( 'created_at', [ $start, $stop ] );
    }
))->get();
```

This works great except for that I need to be able to combine these values on the date and website_id in case a day of revenue or spend was missed. I tried what I have below but it loads forever.

```
public function daily_data() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Spend', 'website_id', 'id')->
    selectRaw('sum(spend.spend) as spend, sum(spend.clicks) as clicks, sum(spend.leads) as leads, spend.website_id, sum(spend.impressions) as impressions, sum(revenue.revenue) as revenue, sum(revenue.users) as users, avg( revenue.cpm ) as cpm, DATE( revenue.created_at ) as date' )->
    join( 'revenue', DB::raw( 'spend.website_id' ), '=', DB::raw( 'revenue.website_id AND DATE( spend.created_at ) = DATE( revenue.created_at )' ) )->
    groupBy( DB::raw( 'spend.website_id, DATE( spend.created_at )' ) )->
    orderBy( DB::raw( 'DATE( spend.created_at )' ) );
}

Website::with( array(
    'daily_data' => => function( $query ) use ( $start, $stop ) {
        $query->whereBetween( 'created_at', [ $start, $stop ] );
    }
))->get();
```

Any ideas on how to combine these queries within this relationship, or after calling for the individual relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm impressed by how far you have pushed the Eloquent relation system. I tried a few of those tricks myself at some point. But i finally changed my point of view recently, especially regarding stats.

You do not need Eloquent to get stats based on multiple group by and so on. Eloquent is meant for things like CRUD, handling events with observers, using scopes, mutators and eager loading, and it is really great in many cases.

In your situation i would recommend that you write raw sql queries all by yourself, in the end you will have better control over it.

Apart from that, if your query is really too long to execute you can

- Check SQL execution plan & missing indexes in order to optimize
- If this does not solve the performance issue you will need to consolidate datas in a specific stat table, meaning you will store all the results from that  daily_stats query/relation, using a scheduled task to refresh that table by truncating & executing query again every hour. This will ensure that your stats pop very fast on the UI. Plus as the query runs in background you do not care if it takes minutes to exec....